# WSO2 Identity Server dashboard apps

Tags: wso2, server, identity, dashboard, wso2-identity-server

I am evaluating WSO2 IS for our company and I can't find any reference on how to get apps to appear on the user dashboard.

I have everything else working as expected and this is the last thing and it has beaten me.

Any pointers to examples or a the correct document would be great.

Comment: Did you refer Please refer WSO2 Identity server 5.0.0 [1]?
  [1]: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Working+with+the+Dashboard

Comment: Yes I did thanks. This tells you "Once you have logged in, click View details under Authorized Apps. The following page appears, listing out the available apps." but does not give any info on how to create 'authorised app' entries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an access token with the generated oauth app, then it'll under Authorized Apps